# cumulative product over a big MySQL table

Tags: mysql

I have a big MySQL table on which I'd like to calculate a cumulative product. This product has to be calculated for each group, a group is defined by the value of the first column.

For example :

```
name | number | cumul | order
-----------------------------
a    | 1      | 1     | 1
a    | 2      | 2     | 2
a    | 1      | 2     | 3
a    | 4      | 8     | 4
b    | 1      | 1     | 1
b    | 1      | 1     | 2
b    | 2      | 2     | 3
b    | 1      | 2     | 4
```

I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276790/mysql-cumulative-sum-grouped-by-date) but don't think it would be efficient to join or subselect in my case.

I've seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2563918/create-a-cumulative-sum-column-in-mysql) which is what I want except it does not partition by name.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  A solution to this might require heavy use of session variables, and it might be a big job.

Comment: Do you already have an `order` column, or would that need to be computed as well?

Comment: How "big" is your table?

Comment: Thanks for your help guys, but Gordon's answer is just perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to a cumulative sum:

```
select t.*,
       (@p := if(@n = name, @p * number,
                 if(@n := name, number, number)
                )
       ) as cumul
from t cross join
     (select @n := '', @p := 1) params
order by name, `order`;
```