# Sql query to add consecutive row values until a condition is met

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a small SQL table as follows:

```sql
    create table temp (
        company varchar2(10) not null,
        sales NUMBER,
        parent_b VARCHAR2(10),
        PRIMARY KEY (company),
        CONSTRAINT company_branch_reference FOREIGN KEY (parent_b)
        REFERENCES temp(company)
    );
```

The contents of the table are as follows:

```
+---------+-------+----------+
| COMPANY | SALES | PARENT_B |
+---------+-------+----------+
| A1      |    20 | A1       |
| A2      |    30 | A1       |
| A3      |    30 | A1       |
| A4      |    40 | A2       |
| A5      |    10 | A2       |
| A6      |    20 | A3       |
| B1      |    40 | B1       |
| B2      |    20 | B1       |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

In this case, each company has a reference to the parent company.
For example, **A1** itself is a parent so the **Parent** column has **A1**
for **A2, A3** the **Parent** column has **A1**

I want to calculate the total sales of each parent as follows:
The parent **A1** has a total sale of 20+30+30+40+10+20 = **150**
The parent **B1** has a total sale of 40+20 = **60**

The output should be as follows:

```
+----------+-------+
| Parent_b | Sales |
+----------+-------+
| A1       |   150 |
| B1       |    60 |
+----------+-------+
```

Can someone please help me out with a MySQL query for this scenario.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: first, is it mysql or oracle? second if A1 company does not have real parent, then dont use A1 as parent. this complicates everything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22276790/mysql-cumulative-sum-grouped-by-date

Comment: And if MySQL, then which version?

Comment: @DervişKayımbaşıoğlu I am using oracle database 19c

Comment: @PradnyaAlchetti then you can use the query I have given, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Oracle you can use Hierarchial query to solve this:

```
WITH CTE1 AS (SELECT a.*, LEVEL, CONNECT_BY_ROOT COMPANY AS PARENT
FROM table1 a
START WITH  parent_b IN ('A1', 'B1')
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE PRIOR  company = parent_b)
SELECT SUM(SALES), PARENT FROM CTE1 
WHERE PARENT IN ('A1', 'B1') 
GROUP BY PARENT;
```